# Can anyone explain the columns of summary report in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is the average showing in milliseconds? How the error % is calculating, on the what basis total value of average and error % calculating?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) guide:

**#Samples** is the number of samples with the same label.

**Average** is the average time of a set of results.

**Median** is a number which divides the samples into two equal halves. Half of the samples are smaller than the median, and half are larger. [Some samples may equal the median.] This is a standard statistical measure. The Median is the same as the 50th Percentile.

**90% Line** (90th Percentile) meaning 90% of the samples took no more than this time.
Median is the time in the middle of a set of results. 50% of the samples took no more than this time; the remainder took at least as long.

**Min** is the shortest time for the samples with the same label

**Max** is the longest time for the samples with the same label

**Error %** is the percent of requests with errors

**Throughput** is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.

**Kb/sec** - throughput measured in Kilobytes per second. Time is in milliseconds.